# query runs fine in sql developer, but crashes in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, oracle10g

When I run this in sqldeveloper:

```
SELECT   CASE
WHEN TABLE1.COL1 IS NOT NULL
THEN (
CASE
WHEN TABLE1.COL2 IS NOT NULL
THEN TABLE1.COL3
ELSE TABLE1.COL4
END) 
WHEN TABLE1.COL5 IS NOT NULL
THEN TABLE1.COL6
ELSE TABLE1.COL7 END "C" FROM TABLE1
```

it runs fine.
When I run this through a Hibernate session, it gives:

```
No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101
```

All cols are of type varchar2. col1 is of type number.
The database is oracle 10g.
A workaround is also welcome, if a solution is not obvious :)
Also, how can I find out what is the JDBC type  -101 referring to. I have seen -1 but not -101 before.

EDIT: I tried using a return scalar on top of the named query No luck.
EDIT#2: Is there a way to see what is the datatype returned for "C". Then I use one of the solutions provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if axtavt's answer doesn't work you can define your own type mapping following this pattern:

```
public class MySQL5Dialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
{
    public MySQL5Dialect()
    { 
        super(); // register additional hibernate types for default use in scalar sqlquery type auto detection 
        registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, Hibernate.TEXT.getName()); 
    }

}
```

Of course you have to use the value you are getting instead ov longvarchar and the apropriate Hiberante types.

(I nicked the code sample here: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1483

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when we pass a parameter through query rather than putting the value directly. In case of SQL you can regenerate the same by giving value as C= :S and entering the value in the new textbox generated. Solution to this problem comes in an upgrade patch as this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I've never faced it on Oracle, but sometimes JDBC returns strange types for complex expressions in queries, and Hibernate can't resolve these types.

In such cases you can try to add explicit cast to the query:

```
SELECT CAST((CASE ... END) AS varchar2) "C" FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Thanks. Upon doing this, it shows:java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qctcte1], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []. Works fine in sql developer though. Btw, what is qctcte1?

Comment: @Kaushik: I don't have much experience with Oracle, so I don't know what to do with it.